# How to save image into photo gallery of samsung,Lg,Nokia mobiles using j2me

Tags: mobile, java-me, nokia, samsung-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save an image into photo gallery using j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150418/how-to-save-an-image-into-photo-gallery-using-j2me)

I am working on an application in which i want to download an image from internet and save it to photo gallery of every mobile. Please provide me suggestion.
Thanks,

Comment: why you are posting same question ?

Comment: Visit this [link][1] for your answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150418/how-to-save-an-image-into-photo-gallery-using-j2me

Comment: Also look on this discussion, [how to download image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226245/how-to-download-images-from-a-computer-webserver-to-a-phone-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void downloadImage(String folder, String photoName, String url) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] rawImg = null;
        try
        {
            String imageData = getDataFromUrl(url);
            rawImg = imageData.getBytes();
            putPhotoToPhone(rawImg, folder, photoName);
        }
        catch(Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getDataFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {

        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream is = null;
        HttpConnection c = null;

        long len = 0 ;
        int ch = 0;
        c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
        is = c.openInputStream();
        len = c.getLength();
        if( len != -1)
        {
            for(int i =0 ; i < len ; i++ )
            {
                if((ch = is.read()) != -1)
                {
                    b.append((char) ch);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1)
            {
                len = is.available() ;
                b.append((char)ch);
            }
        }
        is.close();
        c.close();
        return b.toString();
    }
    private void putPhotoToPhone(byte[] rawImg, String photoDir, String imageName)
    {
        FileConnection fcDir, fcFile;
        String pRoot = "Phone:/";
        OutputStream os;
        if (rawImg != null)
        {
            try
            {
                fcDir = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///"+pRoot+photoDir+"/", Connector.READ_WRITE);
                if (!fcDir.exists())
                    fcDir.mkdir();
                fcFile = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///"+pRoot+photoDir+"/"+imageName, Connector.READ_WRITE);
                if (fcFile.exists())
                    fcFile.delete();
                fcFile.create();
                os = fcFile.openOutputStream();
                os.write(rawImg);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                fcFile.close();
                fcDir.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,it is that what i am searching.

Comment: so accept the answer by clicking the ckeck-mark and upvote the answer